# Cannot read property 'status' of undefined build:android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm going to upload a keystore for my react-native app , so I run this command into my terminal and I get this error

> Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
>   at _getForPlatformAsync (/@expo/xdl@55.0.14/src/Project.js:163:70)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

This is my `app.json`:

```
{
    "expo": {
        "name": "LostInTunisia",
        "slug": "LostInTunisia",
        "privacy": "public",
        "sdkVersion": "33.0.0",
        "platforms": [
            "ios",
            "android",
            "web"
        ],
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
        "splash": {
            "image": "./assets/splash.png",
            "resizeMode": "contain",
            "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
        },
        "updates": {
            "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
        },
        "assetBundlePatterns": [
            "**/*"
        ],
        "ios": {
            "bundleIdentifier": "com.yourcompany.LostInTunisia"
        },
        "android": {
            "package": "com.yourcompany.LostInTunisia"
        }
    }
}
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
    "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web",
        "eject": "expo eject"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "expo": "^33.0.0",
        "expo-facebook": "^5.0.1",
        "react": "16.8.3",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
        "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.10.1",
        "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
        "react-navigation": "^3.11.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-preset-expo": "^5.1.1"
    },
    "private": true
}
```

Comment: please upload the code where the error is showing i.e (src/Project.js:163:70)

Comment: Please upload the code

Answer (score 0):

mostly it can be this.
you have declared something like error=androidError||{}
it assumes error be undefined.
so when u rite error.status it will show type error cannot access status on undefined.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.